# No puedo hacer un sort de un arrayList de objetos - Java

Tags: java

Tengo que mostrar un `Arraylist` de objeto persona por el nombre de `A-Z`.
La información que encuentro es con un `sort` pero no se implementarlo. mi código esta así:

**Clase persona**

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Persona {

private String nombre, apellido, dni;
private GregorianCalendar fechaNaci;

public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, String dni, GregorianCalendar fechaNaci) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.fechaNaci = fechaNaci;
}



public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public GregorianCalendar getFechaNaci() {
    return fechaNaci;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nombre + "\t\t" + apellido + "\t\t" + dni + "\t" + fechaNaci.get(fechaNaci.DAY_OF_MONTH) +"/"+fechaNaci.get(fechaNaci.MONTH) +"/"+fechaNaci.get(fechaNaci.YEAR);
}
```

**Menú de la aplicación**
Introduzco los datos de forma automática para hacer las pruebas.

```
class Pers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Persona> arPersona = new ArrayList<Persona>();

        arPersona.add(new Persona("Brian", "Flores Maya asd", "76587515M", new GregorianCalendar(1995, 11, 06)));
        arPersona.add(new Persona("Samu", "Martin Martin", "34509475F", new GregorianCalendar(1996, 8, 11)));
        arPersona.add(new Persona("Arthur", "Alcovendo", "82340945D", new GregorianCalendar(1997, 03, 23)));
        arPersona.add(new Persona("Josep", "Torrent Garcia", "98734561L", new GregorianCalendar(1993, 12, 14)));

        int opcion = 0;
        do {
            opcion = menu();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    arPersona.add(introduirPersona());
                    break;
                case 2:

                    ordenarAZ(arPersona);
                case 3:

                    break;
                case 4:

                    break;
                case 5:

                    break;
                case 6:

                    break;
                case 7:

                    break;
                case 8:

                    break;
                case 9:

                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcio incorrecta");
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 0);

    }//fin main

    public static void ordenarAZ(ArrayList<Persona> arPersonas) {
        //Mostrar les persones ordenades per nom (A-Z).





       // Collections.sort(arPersonas.get());
        for (Persona x : arPersonas) {

            System.out.println(x.toString());
        }

    }//fin ordenarAZ

    public static Persona introduirPersona() {
        String nom = Teclado.leerString("Introdueix el nom: ");
        String cognom = Teclado.leerString("Introdueix el cognom: ");
        String dni = Teclado.leerString("Introdueix el DNI: ");
        GregorianCalendar data = Teclado.leerData("Introdueix una data: ");

        Persona persona = new Persona(nom, cognom, dni, data);

        return persona;
    }//fin intorduirPersona

    public static int menu() {
        int opcion = 0;
        System.out.println("1.- Introduïr persona\n"
                + "2.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per nom (A-Z).\n"
                + "3.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per nom (Z-A).\n"
                + "4.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per cognoms (A-Z).\n"
                + "5.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per cognoms (Z-A).\n"
                + "6.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per NIF (1-9).\n"
                + "7.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per NIF (9-1).\n"
                + "8.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per data de naixement (1-9).\n"
                + "9.- Mostrar les persones ordenades per data de naixement (9-1).\n"
                + "0. Sortir");
        opcion = Teclado.leerInt("Opcio: ");
        return opcion;
    }//fin menu

}
```

¿Cómo puedo ordenar el `ArrayList` de  personas de la A a la Z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si le está permitido o usa `Java 8` , puede utilizar la interfaz [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) para realizar la comparación de forma más legible. Concatenando las comparaciones con [thenComparing()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) con los atributos que desee. *(1 o más de 1)* esto después de [comparing()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

```
arPersona.sort(Comparator.comparing(Persona::getApellido)
        .thenComparing(Persona::getNombre));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya funciona :D

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas ordenar por nombre y apellido, te recomiendo que en tu clase implementes la interfaz [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) y comparar por dichos campos:

```
public class Persona implements Comparable {
  ...

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Persona other) {
    int res = this.apellido.compareTo(other.apellido);
    if (res != 0) // Si los apellidos son iguales, compara por nombre
      res = this.nombre.compareTo(other.nombre);
    return res;
  }
}
```

Y luego simplemente usas:

```
Collections.sort(arPersonas);
```

Comment: Gracias, la idea ya cogiendo forma. El problema ahora es que cuando hace el Collections.sort(arPersona); el programa peta dandome este error:   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.